# Swing components to be written as XML

Tags: java, xml, swing

I wanted to convert and save a Java GUI (`JFrame` and Java components etc.) into an XML file so that later on I can parse it into web.

I've done some reading in some websites/blogs on something like *how to write XML files in Java*, so does this mean that I will have to implement my own format conversion of Java components? Just wanted to make sure if I'm on the right track of reading. Or if there is a more direct way of doing this from other's experiences?

Comment: In just about every [Swing Component's JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) there is this statement - *"Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeans™ has been added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder."*

Comment: You can read more about [`XMLEncoder` here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence4-140124.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you again! :D

Comment: If you don't have to use swing use [JavaFx](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm) which has native support for [xml](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm).

Comment: @c0der yeah, I read about JavaFX after doing my GUI. I can't play around it at the moment. Maybe next time :)